# Python saving and import from CSV Treeview

Tags: python

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwmYw.jpg)Hello I wrote a program in tkinter (Python) and I have a problem with saving and importing CSV to area treeview. I just can't save the content of table to csv and display it in treeview. I dont use any sql database. Just problem with saving content of table and display it in program table. Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
import csv
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo,askquestion
    root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

one = StringVar()
two = StringVar()
three = StringVar()
four = StringVar()
    def quit():
    MsgBox = askquestion('Exit Application','Are you sure you want to exit the application',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
        root.destroy()
def save():
    with open("new.csv","w",newline='') as f:
        w=csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        w.writerow(tree.get_children())
        showinfo("Save to CSV file","File was saved")
def add_medicine():
    row = tree.insert("",END,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),cal1.get()))
    e0.delete(0,END)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
def select(event):
    try:
        cursor = tree.focus()
        content = tree.item(cursor)
        row = content["values"]
        one.set(row[0])
        two.set(row[1])
        three.set(row[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
def delete_all():
    for i in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(i)
def edit():
    try:
        x = tree.selection()[0]
        for item in x:
            tree.item(x,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),cal1.get()))
    except IndexError:
        pass
def remove_item():
    selected_items = tree.selection()[0]
    tree.delete(selected_items)
def open_CSV():
    with open("new.csv") as myfile:
        csvread = csv.reader(myfile,delimiter=",")
        for i in csvread:
            print(i)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25,selectmode=EXTENDED)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ilość ampułek")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKWKK.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxG6l.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPkh0.jpg)
```

Comment: Some essential code seems to be missing (how and where are the function called) whereas some imports are not used. Please make sure you post some kind of a minimal working example, I couldn't get this one to work.

Comment: Can anybody knows solution please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question remains unclear. However.

1. In the `open_CSV()` function you can replace the `print(i)` statement with `tree.insert("", "end", "", text="", values=(i))`.
2. You must call the `open_CSV()` function somewhere after `tree["show"]="headings"`.
3. Immediately after that, you should place tree on the window: `tree.pack()`
4. You must call `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code.

This produces at least some results, but not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: OK I try to explain. When it comes to saving to file. I add some lines to my treeview. And there is some records. When I stop adding items to treeview I click button save to file and when I open the document there are letters like I001, I002, I003 in CSV document. I can't write the code as I see these rows in the table I just added.

Comment: It worked partly because all four columns showed in one. How to do it to show datas in every single column?

Comment: Solving this problem is: tree.insert("", "end", "", text="", values=(i[0])).I gave [0] after i

Comment: Now the problem saving to file